# Recursive derivative formula of $\frac{1}{a+bx}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, induction, recurrence-relations

I've been struggling with this problem. I'm asked to find a recursive formula for the derivatives of this function:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{a+bx}$$
and then to prove the formula I've found with induction.

**Attempted solution:**

By differentiating this formula multiple times I've found that (we'll call this formula (1)):
$$f^n(x) = (-1)^n(n!)b^n(a+bx)^{-(n+1)}  $$

Or alternatively (we'll call this formula (2)):
$$f^n(x)= (-nb)f^{n-1}(x)*f^0(x) $$

Which formula is the correct one? I think it's (2).
I also have trouble proving those with induction. I can only prove one by using them both.
That's what I've done:

if $n=1$, basically
$$f'(x) = -b(a+bx)^{-1}$$
for $n+1$ we should find that:
$$f^{n+1}(x)= (-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!b^{n+1}(a+bx)^{-n-2}$$
we'll call this formula (3)
We also know that:
$f^{n+1}(x) = \frac {d}{dx} f^n(x)$, so, using (2):
$$f^{n+1}(x) = \frac {d}{dx} ((-nb)f^{n-1}(x)*f^0(x)) = (-nb)(f^{n}(x)*f^0(x)+f^{n-1}*f^1(x))$$
Then, using (1):
$$f^{n+1}(x) =(-nb)*[(-1)^n(n!)b^n(a+bx)^{-n-1}*(a+bx)^{-1} + (-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!b^{n-1}(a+bx)^{-n-2}*(a+bx)^{-2}(-b) ]  
=$$

$$=(-nb)[(-1)^n(b^n)(a+bx)^{-n-2}(n-1)!(n+1)]=(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!(b^{n+1})(a+bx)^{-n-2}$$

Which is exactly (3). Is my method correct? I think it's a bit messy and I've only succeeded in proving (1) when I wanted to prove (2) too.

Comment: Yes but with the chain rule you still have to differentiate z ($\frac{dz}{dx}$) so i still have to keep $b^n$

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that it's often quite possible that both equations are correct. I'm not saying that that's the case here, but the fact that you found two different expressions for the same thing doesn't necessarily mean something is wrong.

Comment: They're both recursive though? I'm not really sure about that...   
@Isham I understood what you're saying, sorry! I think that my biggest problem is still the proof. The formulas are easy enough.

Comment: The first formula is not recursive. A recursive formula for a sequence $a_n$ is a formula that expressed $a_n$ in terms of (some of) $a_{n-1}, a_{n-2},\ldots a_0$. The second formula does this, while the first does not. In practice only a few of the lower-terms is likely to  be used, such as in your second formula or in the recursive formula $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$, for the Fibonacci numbers

Comment: Ok thanks @StellaBiderman ! Any idea on how I can prove it?

Comment: I was going to post an answer approximately the same as what AlkaKadri posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your formulas are correct, but if you want something *recursive*, you number 2 is what you're looking for:
$$f^n(x)= (-nb)f^{n-1}(x)*f(x) \tag{2}$$
(Here I've used $f(x) \equiv f^0(x)$).

For your induction step, assuming that $f^n(x)= (-nb)f^{n-1}(x)*f(x)$, you have:
\begin{align}
  f^{n + 1} &:= \frac{d}{dx}f^n(x)\\
  &= \frac{d}{dx}[(-nb)f^{n-1}(x)*f(x)]\ \text{ (by the I.H)}\\
  &= (-nb)(f^n(x)f(x) + f^{n - 1}f'(x))
\end{align}
Use the induction hypothesis (I.H) again on $f'(x)$ to get $f'(x) = (-(1)b)f(x)f(x)$. Then,
\begin{align}
  f^{n + 1}(x) &= (-nb)f^n(x)f(x) + (-nb)(-b)f^{n - 1}f(x)f(x)
\end{align}
Once again, use the I.H to substitute $(-nb)f^{n - 1}f(x) = f^n(x)$. Finally,
\begin{align}
  f^{n + 1}(x) &= (-nb)f^n(x)f(x) + (-b)f^n(x)f(x)\\
  &= (-(n + 1)b)f^nf(x)
\end{align}
as desired.